# Optimising "if number in list" in python

Tags: python

I have a big (~10<sup>6</sup>) list of floats in python, to which I make repeated calls `if number in list`. The list does not change. Is there any way to speed this process up, say by sorting the list, and taking advantage of its being sorted?

Comment: turn the list into a set

Answer (score 0):

You should change your list to set (or frozenset if set is constant).

Example:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
s = set(l)  # frozenset(l)
obj in l  # O(n) lookup
obj in s  # O(1) lookup
```

Comment: You'd probably say something about the efficiency of `set(big_list_with_1000000_elements)`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn the list into a set in order to remove duplicates and optimize membership tests.
2. Ensure the set is loaded only once into RAM
3. Use [the array bisection algorithm](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) if needing to work with a sorted list (i.e. you don't want to eliminate duplicates, need to make inserts, etc.).

If attempting to calculate the time complexity of both option, [see this handy reference.](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the list into a set, which can take a lot of memory and computation times for creation (and which will remove duplicates).

Alternatively or you can use the module [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/bisect.html) to take advantage of the fact that your list is sorted.  The first has search time of `O(1)` and the second of `O(log(n))`.